# how to pass databasename as parameter in stored procedure while creating from bteq in teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

I am creating a stored procedure from bteq in teradata. I created one .sql file and compiling through bteq.

```
.COMPILE FILE =path/scriptname.sql;
```

in the scriptname.sql, i have stored procedure structure.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE $database1.RTQ0040_SP_1_1
(
param1
)
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR
LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS
SELECT * from $dababase2.table where rname=:param1;

OPEN cur1;
END;
```

my concern about how to pass those $database1 and $database2. how to pass database names here.

Comment: You would have to make any substitutions into the SQL file text outside of BTEQ. And you should declare a data type for `param1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off 
:: This is a comment

Copy NUL RunSP.bteq 
:: If you have a generic logon details in place write those details to this bteq file using the below line
:: To use th below just un comment it 
:: echo .run file = 'LOGON.BTQ' >> RunSP.bteq 

:: $database1 shall be provided as input parameter 1 for this bat file 
echo REPLACE PROCEDURE %1.RTQ0040_SP_1_1 >> RunSP.bteq
echo ( >> RunSP.bteq
echo param1 >> RunSP.bteq
echo ) >> RunSP.bteq

echo DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 >> RunSP.bteq
echo BEGIN >> RunSP.bteq
echo DECLARE cur1 CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR >> RunSP.bteq
echo LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS >> RunSP.bteq
:: $database2 shall be provided as input parameter 2 for this bat file 
echo SELECT * from %2.table where rname=:param1; >> RunSP.bteq

echo OPEN cur1; >> RunSP.bteq
echo END; >> RunSP.bteq

:: You can the execute this bteq script from this bat itself 
:: This way using this bat file as an interface you are making the bteq script dynamic by passing the parameters to the bat file and executing the bteq script from this bat file. So you just need to call this bat file only. 

:: code to execute this bteq script from this bat file 
:: But to call the bteq script from a bat file you must first logon, i.e provide the logon credentials into the bteq file 
::bteq < RunSP.bteq > Output.out
```

From the command prompt go to the folder where the bat file containing the above code is present. Run the bat file using the above code:

```
BatFileName.bat param1 param2
```

Here param1 and param2 are the parameters that means the databases names.

Here the bteq script is built dynamically using a bat file.